# Replace string only at end of a line

Tags: c#

I'm using C# replace text in a string but failing when the text is at the end of line.

```
string filepent = filehex.Replace(",,,,,\r\n", ",EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY");
```

I am loading a txt file into a filestream and then converting to a string. I want to replace a anywhere where it says ",,,,," at the end of a line. Currently the code above only changes it at the end of the file. At the end of a line where it should change it my hex editor says there is .. or 0D 0A

Thanks

Comment: C has no datatype named `string`, and C++'s `std::string` has no member function `Replace()`. It would be hard for people to help you use some API they've never heard of! Can you edit your question to clarify somewhat what language you're using, and what `string` type we're talking about?

Comment: Looks like you are handling the file as one line of text. The solution: split the file in array of lines (or read it line by line), and then apply the replace function on each line separately. I could be wrong though, im not c# guy. nor do i understand your code what it actually does, so use my comment with precaution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be tempted to instead split the file using [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx), make the replacement, then join them back together.  Maybe not the most performant, but clearly expresses your goal.  Something like:

```
string matchPattern = ",,,,,$"; // $ to match the end of the line.
string replacement = ",EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY,EMPTY";
string filepent = String.Join(
    Environment.NewLine, // or maybe just "\r\n"
    File.ReadAllLines(yourFilePath)
        .Select(line => Regex.Replace(line, matchPattern, replacement)));
```

Comment: If you're writing the modified string to a file, you don't need to join it manually, you can instead use `File.WriteAllLines()`.